# Como posso remover linha de tabela com jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Criei uma tabela com dois botões um tem como função adicionar novas linhas a tabela e outro remove-las.

Testei desta forma e apenas consigo adicionar novas linhas, quando tento remover acontece um erro.

```js
var table = $( '#table-data' )[0];

$( table ).delegate( '.tr_clone_add', 'click', function () {
    var thisRow = $( this ).closest( 'tr' )[0];
    $( thisRow ).clone().insertAfter( thisRow ).find( 'input:text' ).val( '' );
});

$( table ).undelegate( '.tr_clone_del', 'click', function () {
    var thisRow = $( this ).closest( 'tr' )[0];
    $( thisRow ).clone().delete( thisRow ).find( 'input:text' ).val( '' );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table-data">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>From</td>
        <td>To</td>
        <td>Add</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
        <td><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="who" name="who"></td>
        <td><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="location" name="location" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Start Date" name="datepicker_start" class="datepicker"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="End Date" name="datepicker_end" class="datepicker"></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add"></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="del" value="del" class="tr_clone_del"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Não entendi o que é que você está perguntando. Qual é a sua dúvida exatamente?

Comment: com a class "tr_clone_add" adiciono nova linha e com a class"tr_clone_del" pretendo remover

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para a remoção da linha basta você pode utilizar o [.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) que removerá o elemento que for passado como parâmetro do `DOM`.

```
$(table).delegate( '.tr_clone_del', 'click', function () {
    var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
    thisRow.remove();
});
```

**Obs.:**

Aqui estamos utilizando a versão **2.1.1** do *Jquery* mas vale lembrar que a partir da versão **3.0** os métodos [.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) e [.undelegate()](http://api.jquery.com/undelegate/) estão obsoletos e devem ser substituidos por [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) e [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) respectivamente.

Segue exemplo abaixo, utilizando `delegate()`.

```js
var table = $( '#table-data' )[0];

$(table).delegate( '.tr_clone_add', 'click', function () {
    var thisRow = $( this ).closest( 'tr' )[0];
    $( thisRow ).clone().insertAfter( thisRow ).find( 'input:text' ).val( '' );
});

$(table).delegate( '.tr_clone_del', 'click', function () {
    var thisRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
    thisRow.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="table-data">
    <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Location</td>
        <td>From</td>
        <td>To</td>
        <td>Add</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr_clone">
        <td><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="who" name="who"></td>
        <td><input type="text" autofocus placeholder="location" name="location" ></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="Start Date" name="datepicker_start" class="datepicker"></td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="End Date" name="datepicker_end" class="datepicker"></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="add" value="Add" class="tr_clone_add"></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="del" value="del" class="tr_clone_del"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: valeu mais ainda com observação on/off - delegate/undelegate